# Android annotations @EBean rebind(Context context)

Tags: android, android-annotations

When I use `setRetainInstance(true)` for Fragment, field annotated with `@Bean` like below

```
@Bean
Navigator navigator;
```

does not update activity context after screen rotate.

There is method `rebind(Context context)` in generated class `Navigator_`. I must manually call this function in this way?

```
@AfterViews
void afterViews() {
    ((Navigator_) navigator).rebind(getActivity());
}
```

I think it's not good. May be there special annotations for this case?

Comment: I am not sure about your use case. You are injecting a `Navigator` to a `Fragment` which has retained instance state? And how comes your `Activity` into the picture?

Comment: OK, i see, you want to reinject the context.

Comment: There is a [propositon](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/620) to add `@RetainInstance` annotation to the library. The conversation in it did not take reinjecting into account, so i added a comment. So think you have to rebind manually as you currently do.